# Get parent relation of an object dynamically in Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three models

Product, Variant and Option.

```
class Product {
    public $id;

    public function variants(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
    }
}

class Variant {
    public $id;
    public $product_id;

    public function product(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function options(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
    }
}  

class Option {
    public $id;
    public $variant_id;

    public function variant(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Variant::class);
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way for an instance of Variant to get parent (Product) relationship and for Option
the parent (Variant) relationship with one line of code. Is there anything like the below?

```
$instance->parent();
```

I want to avoid writing

```
If (get_class($instance) === 'Variant' ) {
    $instance->product();
} else if (get_class($instance) === 'Option' ) {
    $instance->variant();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the relation model easily. Like-

```
$variants = \App\Models\Variant::latest()->get();
foreach($variants as $variant)
{
   $product_name = $variant->product->name; // this will be the product name that that related with this variant
}
```

It will be also work for single collection

```
$variant = \App\Models\Variant::find(1)>-first();
$variant->product;// this is product model instance that related to variant
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I asked for.